# How to query the most profitable item in a specific year in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a practice problem where I am to write a query to find the top most 15 percent profitable products in the year 2005 from a database. The database does NOT have attributes like "Saleprice, or Purchaseprice". It has tables like PUrchaseProductDetails or SalesOrderDetails, and other stuff with Unitprice, orderquantity, ProdID, LIstPrice, ActualCost, StandardPrice, etc as attributes. I am confused as to which one I should use and how to come up with a formula. I tried to write a query, but got infinitely running results.

```
SELECT A.ProdID, B.ProdID, A.Unitprice - (B.Unitprice * orderquantity) Profit 
FROM SalesOrderDetails A join PurchaseOrderD B
ON A.ProdID = B.ProdID
WHERE year(DateOrdered) = 2005
Group by A.ProdID
```

I have spent hours on these type of questions and my brain is at a dead end right now. If someone can please direct me to do it the right way, it would really help me out.

Comment: Table structure and sample data will be more helpful to check out the situation and pick out the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sale.ProdID, sum(sale.Unitprice - buy.Unitprice) * sale.Qty AS profit
FROM SalesOrderDetails AS sale
JOIN PurchaseOrderD AS buy ON ...
WHERE year(...) = 2005
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 15
```

Comment: What does the number 1 do in Group BY? I am fairly new to sql, finding it difficult to workout the problem.

Comment: 1 is shorthand == 1st field in select, 2 == 2nd in select